# Can i use gridview elements like one image then string then checkbox and how?

Tags: android, image, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to develop a android application where I want to show product description and if user wants that product, he clicks corresponding checkbox. For this I think gridview can be good for many elements.

I am trying to do like this;

```
Image   String1    Checkbox
        String1alt
Image2  String2    Checkbox
        String2alt
```

.
.
.

How can I do such a gridview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According me instead of using the gridView you should use listview.

Refer this links.

[LINK](http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/listview-with-checkboxes-without-listactivity.php) listview with checkbox

[LINK1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

[LINK2](http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/)

[LINK3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom)